# Загрузка страницы с SVG файлами

Tags: css, svg, загрузка

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема, что при загрузке страницы svg файлы сначала разносятся на всю страницу, а уже потом подгоняются в заданный размер, очень некрасиво смотрится, preloader не действует на svg файлы, как с этим бороться? Заранее благодарю.

P.S. Вот ссылка на видео, для наглядности

https://yadi.sk/i/tSh_5j1L3GGNf2

Comment: 1. Задайте высоту\ширину контейнерам, в которых находятся свг.
2. `preloader не действует на svg файлы` - сделайте тогда прелоадер на весь сайт :)

Comment: @LiEm Покажите **код** пожалуйста, где вы подключаете SVG файлы в Html.

Comment: 1. У меня всегда есть ширина и высота у контейнеров, в которые я ставлю любое изображение, если бы я ее не давал, то свг файл был бы таким огромным всегда, а не только в мгновение, только при загрузке страницы.

Comment: 2. Я на весь сайт и делаю прилодер а как иначе? Просто свг файлы не поддаются влиянию прилодера, у них почему-то своя жизнь, пнг файлы это другое дело

Comment: Alexandr_T,  <div class="logo"><img src="img/header/logo.svg" alt="Магазин смартфонов  Xiaomi"></div> Вот так подключаю.

Comment: @LiEm что бы внести правки в вопрос нажмите ссылку внизу вопросы "править" и добавить код в описание

Comment: @LiEm Если вам помог чей-то ответ, нажмите на галочку ниже треугольника. Если нет, то уточняйте дополнительными вопросами.

Answer (score 3):

1. Подключать svg файл лучшего всего через тег `<object>`

```html
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="SvgImg.svg" width="200" height="200">
          <img src="SvgImg.png" width="200" height="200" alt="image format png"/>
    </object>
```

1. Браузер не понимающий SVG проигнорирует тег `<object>` и перейдет к
   следующему тегу `<img>` и обработает его, как обычный `HTML` тег и
   выведет картинку. [Подробнее здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047). Так надо делать, если вы
   хотите использовать интерактивность svg и это лучший способ добавления svg файлов в html.
2. Ставить диагноз по TV, а в вашем случае по предложенному видео,- сродни шаманству, но попробую:

У вас вероятнее всего в самом файле svg отсутствует **viewport**, поэтому картинка растягивается в каких-то моментах на весь экран. Браузер, если не указан `viewport` `svg` считает его по умолчанию: **width="100%"** и   **height="100%"** (это и есть viewport по умолчанию)
Поэтому попробуйте явно задать в шапке svg файла viewport и viewBox с равными величинами. 
Например:

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
```

### Кратко:

- Сначала дорабатываете файл svg
- Изменяете способ добавления svg файла в Html страничку

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать скрыть все `svg` и `img` до момента загрузки стилей:

```html
<style>svg, img { display: none; }</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

Ну а в css файле выставляем нужный `display`.